# How to merge values from another dataset with a value containing in the first dataset in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following two sets of data:

I want to merge the above two set of data by the following manner. The variable income is a categorical variable that takes the values from 0 to 16. For each of this value, the column of rank contains exactly one value that is equal to that value from income. I want to attach the value of income that is found in the rank with  the lower and upper limit from the second data set. Any insights on how to do this? I'm new to R.

Comment: You are looking for the `merge` function, something like `merge(df1,df2,all.x = T,by.x = "income",by.y = "rank")`

Comment: You can also take a look at the different forms of join from the dplyr package (sucha s inner join, left_join, right_join and full_join).

Comment: I have tried `merge(dflapopofficial,wagecmp,all.dflapopofficial = T,by.dflapopofficial = "income",by.wagecmp = "rank")`. It gives me a column with only zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The join functions in dplyr can join data frames by means of different variables using a named vector like so `by = c('a' = 'b')`. A solution using dplyr could thus look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

data1 <- tibble(income = c(0, 1, NA))

data2 <- tibble(rank = c(0, 1, 2),
                lowerLimit = c(0, 50, 150),
                upperLimit = c(50, 200, 175))

data1 %>%
  left_join(data2, by = c('income' = 'rank'))

#   income lowerLimit upperLimit
#    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1      0          0         50
# 2      1         50        200
# 3     NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: Sure @vahis100. The line essentially signifies a left join (see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html). ```by = c('income' = 'rank')``` is inserted to specify that 'income' and 'rank' are overlapping variables (which are needed to perform the join).